How to disable rawinput keyboard function?
I have an application that would detect input from the barcode Reader.
Generally it not allow user input from the keyboard.
But now there is a condition that would need allow user to input some data on the textBox with the keyboard.
I tried close the RawInput but seems not work, I still can't input data with the keyboard after close the RawInput.
Here is my code. Is there any other way to disable the RawInput?
public RawInput _rawinput;
public string dataFromReader;
public string myReaderDeviceName = "myReaderDevice";

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _rawinput = new RawInput(this.Handle);
    _rawinput.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
}

public void OnKeyPressed(object sender, InputEventArg e)
{
    if (e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceName == myReaderDeviceName)
    {
        dataFromReader += e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName;
    }
}

public void SomeSpecialCondition()
{
    _rawinput.ReleaseHandle(); //not working
    
    string acc = string.Empty;
    string pwd = string.Empty;
    
    //still can't input with keyboard.
    if (Dialogs.InputBox("Pls input userId and pwd.", ref acc, ref pwd) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (checkAuth(acc, pwd))
        {
            
        }
    }
}


Is your barcode reader emulating the keyboard or some other reader mode ex. serial? Also in your code it seems you're sending all keyboard events to this RawInput library. Nowhere in your code you seem to be handling the form's KeyPress event, or you need to show where (maybe in the Designer.cs file?).
